# How to replace a string with loc. output?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two dataframes:

*Dataframe_A:*

```
Account_Nbr  Customer_ID   Gender
  1234          A1234       male
  5678            ?        female
```

*Dataframe_B:*

```
Account_Nbr  Customer_ID
  1234          A1234
  5678          B5678
```

And I want to replace '?' in dataframe A with 'B5678', here is my code:

```
Dataframe_A = Dataframe_A.assign(
Customer_ID = lambda x:
[cid if (cid != '?' ) else
 Datafram_B.loc[Datafram_B['Account_Nbr'] == acct, ['Customer_ID']]
 for cid, acct in zip(x.Customer_ID, x.Account_Nbr)]

Dataframe_A
```

But the output is not what I expect:

```
Account_Nbr  Customer_ID   Gender
  1234          A1234       male
  5678       Customer_ID   female
                B5678
```

It looks like it replace the cell with whole series. How can I get the output like this? Thank you.

```
Account_Nbr  Customer_ID   Gender
  1234          A1234       male
  5678          B5678      female
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do the job.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1234, 'A1234', 'male'],
    [5678, '?', 'female']], columns=['Account_Nbr', 'Customer_ID', 'Gender'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1234, 'A1234'],
    [5678, 'B5678']], columns=['Account_Nbr', 'Customer_ID'])

mask = df1['Account_Nbr'] == df2['Account_Nbr']
df1.loc[mask, 'Customer_ID'] = df2[mask]['Customer_ID']

df1.head()
```

Output:

```
   Account_Nbr Customer_ID  Gender
0         1234       A1234    male
1         5678       B5678  female
```

Comment: But it's only for two dataframes with the same number of indexes. So I had left joined df1 with df2 first to get the same indexes, then use the mask to get the result. Thank you very much!